# What is means by redirect */*/ in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

i am using magento 1.7 and i am unable to under with redirect on `*/*/` can anybody explain it

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/');

$this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links in magento constists of three parts: "package", controller und action, e.g. `customer/account/login`

`*` means "in this context". If you are in the Customer-AccountController and in the `indexAction` method then you redirect with `*/*/edit` into `customer/account/edit`

This edit doesn't make sense in the frontend context, but when you are in the backend, then you have normally a `gridAction` and when you click on a row, you are redirected to the `editAction` and the form to edit the entry.